# Simulating outcome of 3 political parties

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, simulation

First I'm sorry I couldn't figure out the most accurate title for this question (suggestions welcome).

Here's the case: I want to implement spinners like the ones on this page: http://www.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2014/senate-model/

I more or less get the idea: for each state I will need a separate instance of a Gaussian random generator (each with its own mean and standard deviation). At each spin, I will need to execute every single one of them to obtain the outcome. I learned about such a function from this page: http://www.protonfish.com/random.shtml

I will only need to know the probability of one party (P(Dem) for example). The other one (P(Rep)) is simply 1 - P(Dem).

But then I figured it will only work for two-parties situation.

What about 3-parties situation (let's say: Nationalist, Religious, and Communist)? Will the same model work (I have the gut feeling it wouldn't) ?

Would you suggest which approach should I take? Or lead me directly to a chapter / topic in statistic that helps me understand better the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulating results for this process is sometimes called a "stick-breaking" process: we start with a 1-unit stick and break it into two pieces. For this example, we call the first piece "Democrats" and set it aside. Then we break the second piece into two pieces and call the first piece "Republicans," and we are left with the third (and in this example, final) piece, which we call "Greens" (or "Libertarians," or whatever). The length of each piece of stick corresponds to the probability of the respective party winning the seat.

At every point, we only have a total of 1 unit of stick -- the stick is simply allocated into smaller pieces -- so the law of total probability is  respected.

The distribution of lengths of the pieces of the stick is often characterized as a [Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution), which is a generalization of the [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) into an arbitrary number of outcomes: the beta distribution is the same as a Dirichlet distribution for two possible outcomes.

You might wonder why one doesn't simply use several normal models, either one for each party, or even $k-1$ for each of $k$ parties. The answer is that the normal distribution has support over the whole real line, which means it would predict with positive probability  $\Pr(\text{Democrats win})$ for each of $\{-10, 10, 100, \pi\}$, none of which are valid *probabilities.* However, one might use normal models if the probability of winning is transformed in some way. A common transformation which takes values on a unit interval to the real line is the logistic transformation $\text{logit}(x)=\log(x)-\log(1-x)$ which is identical to the log of the odds. This *does* have support over the entire real line, so perhaps a normal model would be acceptable. But if you've put your data on a real line, then literally any distribution on the real line is reasonable *prima facie* -- a question you might need to consider is how heavy the tails are. A normal distribution has very light tails, while a Cauchy distribution is notoriously pathological, and a Student's *t*-distribution with more then 1 degree of freedom is a compromise between those two extremes.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I will take a look at this example in python, first to understand it a little better: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/fonnesbeck/Bios366/blob/master/notebooks/Section5_2-Dirichlet-Processes.ipynb

Do you know of a javascript implementation for that?

Comment: Glad to have helped, but I'm sorry, I don't know of a javascript implementation. I do everything in R.

Comment: Hi,

In R, is it part of standard distribution? Or do you have to install a package (like this one maybe? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DPpackage/index.html )

And, by the way, based on your description of stick-breaking, can I simply have two gaussian random-generator functions for each state (and execute the second only in the case Democrat loses..., to find out whether it's Republic / Libertarian). Would that work?

Thanks again!, Raka

Comment: Oh, you just answered that in your edited answer :D thanks.

Comment: Great! Happy hunting.